# Issue with Laravel's Eloquent implicit JSON casting. Associated array casts to indexed array

Tags: laravel, casting, eloquent

I try to use casting in my Model like this one:

```
protected $casts = [
    'thumbnails' => 'array', // also tried 'json' and 'object' 
];
```

While saving, the correct data is put:

```
$thumbnails = ['small' => 'path1.jpeg', 'medium' => 'path2.jpeg', 'large' => 'path3.jpeg'];
$product->images()->create([
    'path' => $imagePath,
    'thumbnails' => $thumbnails
]);

// Saved content of 'thumbnails' field in DB row:
// {"large": "path1.jpeg", "small": "path2.jpeg", "medium": "path3.jpeg"}
```

Then I try get access to this field, I have:

```
$image = Image::find(6);
dd($image->thumbnails);
// array:3 [▼
//   0 => "path1.jpeg"
//   1 => "path2.jpeg"
//   2 => "path3.jpeg"
// ]
```

Instead of

```
// array:3 [▼
//   'small' => "path1.jpeg"
//   'medium' => "path2.jpeg"
//   'large' => "path3.jpeg"
// ]
```

Database field type is json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I added some wrong getter in the Model...

```
/**
 * @return array
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function getThumbnailsAttribute() : array
{
    return resolve(ImageService::class)->getThumbnailUrls($this);
}
```